# Magento 2: How to validate phone number by their country?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Hello i want to validate phone number in my checkout page but i want phone number validation by their country ,if customer select the USA as country then phone number should accept only usa number if customer select China as country then phone number accept only china number how can i do that?

Comment: You should use this https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input. We have used in one of our magento instance and its work well with phone number validation as per selected country.

Comment: @JaiminSutariya Can you help me ? I don't understand how to load UtilsScript, iti.isValidNumber() return null

Answer (score 1):

Validation rules are written in `validation.js` (lib/web/mage/validation.js), so you need override it.
`requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            "Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/rules": "Vendor_Module/js/lib/validation/rules"
        }
    }
};
```

`rules.js`: add rule like this but for countries you want to check.

```
'phoneUK': [
            function (value) {
                return utils.isEmpty(value) || value.length > 9 &&
                    value.match(/^(\(?(0|\+44)[1-9]{1}\d{1,4}?\)?\s?\d{3,4}\s?\d{3,4})$/);
            },
            $.mage.__('Please specify a valid phone number')
        ],
```

Referencec Url: https://www.bitbull.it/en/blog/custom-js-validation-magento2/

You can add your custom rule.

Comment: Your answer is good but i want when the use select the country then selected country validation should fire. Your answer is for specific country validation @RonakChauhan