# Magento2 UK phone number validation

Tags: magento2, validation

Magento2 On contact Us page how can we validate phone nunber to accept only UK numbers?

Answer (score 1):

You can add validation for UK numbers directly to phtml.

Override `/vendor/magento/module-contact/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml` in your theme/module and add

> data-validate="{'phoneUK':true}"

[image: /var/www/html/magento2/magento241/vendor/magento/module-contact/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check this link I think this may be helpful for you :

[UI form validation in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190699/ui-form-validation-in-magento-2)

May be you need to add custom rule, this link may help you for this :

[Magento 2: How to validate phone number by their country?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293089/magento-2-how-to-validate-phone-number-by-their-country)

Answer (score 0):

In your theme, navigate to app/design/frontend/YourVendor/YourTheme/Magento_Contact/layout/contact_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="contactForm">
            <action method="setValidation" ifconfig="contact/contact/enabled">
                <argument name="phone" xsi:type="string">true</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Next, you'll need to add custom JavaScript to enforce the UK phone number validation.

Create a JavaScript file at app/design/frontend/YourVendor/YourTheme/Magento_Contact/web/js/custom-validation.js

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui',
    'mage/validation'
], function($){
    $.validator.addMethod(
        'uk-phone',
        function (value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^(\+?44|0)[\d]{10}$/.test(value);
        },
        $.mage.__('Please specify a valid UK phone number (e.g., +441234567890 or 01234567890).')
    );

    $('.contact-form').validate({
        rules: {
            telephone: {
                required: true,
                uk-phone: true
            }
        }
    });
});
```

In the same contact_index_index.xml file, require your JavaScript file.

```
<head>
    <script src="Magento_Contact::js/custom-validation.js"/>
</head>
```